# Skip or bypass validation in SmartWizard form step

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have total 5 forms in single smart-wizard form ..

and i want to skip 4th form for validation or bypass it or pass with virtual attribute.

http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/smartwizard2-vertical.htm

for 4th form i am using separate form validation method so won't need smart-wizard validation.

Please suggest how it get done ?

if you need more information please comment at below.

thanks